# How to use existing data from the database in Codeception FactoryMuffin?

Tags: codeception, faker, factorymuffin

I'm trying to set up easy test data in my Acceptance tests:

```php
  public function shouldUseAFakeAccountHolder(AcceptanceTester $I) {
    $I->have(AccountHolder::class);
    // ...
  }
```

I've copied [the example code from the Codeception documentation](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/DataFactory) and modified it with my entity names (as well as fixing the bugs).

```php
<?php
public function _beforeSuite()
{
     $factory = $this->getModule('DataFactory');
     // let us get EntityManager from Doctrine
     $em = $this->getModule('Doctrine2')->_getEntityManager();

     $factory->_define(AccountHolder::class, [
         'firstName' => Faker::firstName(),

         // Comment out one of the below 'accountRole' lines before running:

         // get existing data from the database
         'accountRole' => $em->getRepository(AccountRole::class)->find(1),

         // create a new row in the database
         'accountRole' => 'entity|' . AccountRole::class,
     ]);
}
```

The relationship using existing data `'accountRole' => $em->getRepository(AccountRole::class)->find(1)` always fails:

```
 [Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException] A new entity was found through the relationship 'HMRX\CoreBundle\Entity\AccountHolder#accountRole' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: HMRX\CoreBundle\Entity\AccountRole@0000000062481e3f000000009cd58cbd. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'HMRX\CoreBundle\Entity\AccountRole#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

If I tell it to create a new entry in the related table `'accountRole' => 'entity|' . AccountRole::class`, it works, but then it adds rows to the table when it should be using an existing row. All the role types are known beforehand, and a new random role type makes no sense because there's nothing in the code it could match to. Creating a duplicate role works, but again it makes so sense to have a separate role type for each user since roles should be shared by users.

I've had this error before in Unit tests, not Acceptance tests, when not using `Faker` / `FactoryMuffin`, and it's been to do with accessing each entity of the relationship with a different instance of `EntityManager`. As soon as I got both parts using the same instance, it worked. I don't see how to override the native behaviour here though.

Answer (score 0):

It works (at least in Codeception 4.x) by using a callback for the existing relation:

```php
<?php
public function _beforeSuite()
{
     $factory = $this->getModule('DataFactory');
     $em = $this->getModule('Doctrine2')->_getEntityManager();

     $factory->_define(AccountHolder::class, [
         'firstName' => Faker::firstName(),

         'accountRole' => function($entity) use ($em) {
             $em->getReference(AccountRole::class)->find(1);
         },
     ]);
}
```

I've found it here: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/5134#issuecomment-417453633